# Solutions for constant global states in Rust

Tags: rust, constants, state

Currently I am developing a Rust program that should run multiple audio processing nodes on microcontrollers. Therefore I discovered that the processing is much faster, when I do for loops over constant values. That's why each node has a constant state. I tried several strategies to set the state but none of them made me truly happy. It is way easier to define a static state, but I have not found something really nice for constants.

#### 1. const generics

```
struct NodeA<const INPUT_LEN: usize, const OUTPUT_LEN: usize>;
```

This is a good way to configure the Node, but first it is getting ugly when there are too many items in the state, plus I have to constant arrays for the state as well, that are not allowed in const generics yet.

#### 2. Associated Constants in Traits

This solution was making me happy for a whole while. I was defining constants in a trait and made the node generic over the trait so I could configure the Node from outside.

```
pub trait NodeAConfig {
   const INPUT_LEN: usize;
   const AUDIO_STATE: &'static [f32];
}

pub struct NodeA<Config: NodeAConfig>;
impl<Config: NodeAConfig> NodeA<Config> {
    pub fn process() {
        for i in 0..Config::INPUT_LEN {
           todo();
        }
    }
}

struct MyConfig;
impl NodeAConfig for MyConfig {
   const INPUT_LEN: usize = 10;
   const AUDIO_STATE: &[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
}

NodeA<MyConfig>::process();
```

The downside is, that I can't find a solution to put those Configs into an enum and this enum into an array to automatically load a configuration of nodes, because traits with constants can't be made into an object with dyn.

```
enum Configs { NodeA(Box<dyn NodeAConfig>) };
vec![Configs::NodeA(MyConfig);
```

#### 3. const struct

The solution I am happiest with is to use structs and define constant implementations of the struct, that way I can even call const functions in the config and put the configs into an array over an enum.

```
pub struct NodeAConfig {
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub input_shape: [usize; 3],
    pub size: usize,
}

pub struct NodeBConfig {
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub input_shape: [usize; 3],
    pub len: usize,
}

pub enum NodeConfig {
   NodeA(NodeAConfig),
   NodeB(NodeBConfig),
}

pub struct Config<const NODES: usize> {
  pub nodes: [NodeConfig; NODES];
}

impl<const NODES: usize> Config <Nodes> {
   pub const fn config_a<const ID: usize>(&self) -> NodeAConfig {
         match self.node_configs[ID] {
            ...
         }
   }
}
```

Now the Config can be implented as a constant in the top layer:

```
pub const CONFIG: Config<2> = Config {
    nodes: [
        NodeConfig::NodeA(NodeAConfig {
            name: &"NodeA",
            input_shape: [2, 2, 2],
            size: 10,
        }),
        NodeConfig::NodeB(NodeBConfig {
            name: &"NodeB",
            input_shape: [2, 2, 2],
            len: 10,
        }),
    ],
};
```

And the nodes themselves have a const generic ID with which they can get their config from the list of nodes.

```
pub struct NodeA<const ID: usize>;
impl<const ID: usize> NodeA<ID> {
   const CONFIG: NodeAConfig = CONFIG::config_a::<ID>();
}
```

Now the only problem is, that the Nodes must have a reference on the CONFIG object, so this object needs to be defined inside the crate. My goal would be to define this const CONFIG object outside, in a library that is actually using the nodes processor.
Even when I define a yaml or json file and write the config inside the crate with a build.rs file , this yaml file needs to be in the crate and I can't place it in the prgoram that is using my library right?

Is there a solution that I have overseen, or do you think there is a better way of defining a const state?

Comment: It's interesting that iterating over `const`s is faster. Anyway, can you use nightly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem with the "Associated Constants in Traits" approach. Do you want to load a configuration at runtime?

Comment: Couldn't the `Configs` enum be `enum Configs { NodeA(NodeA<MyConfig>), NodeB(NodeB<MyConfig>), ... }`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 1. I think the compiler can unfold the for loop and lay it out more nicely when the loop is a constant. Nightly might be possible, I am just afraid that something makes me regret using nightly when I have to deliver the app. In nightly I just tested to use the const generics with structs, but it is very limited what can be inside of the struct then.
2. I don't want to load it at runtime, the Box I was suggesting in the trait enum would not work anyway. I just want to be able to configure the sequence and constant values from outside the crate at compile time.

Comment: 1. Why limited? With `adt_const_params` you should be able to use `&str` or arrays in const generics. Is there someone you want but cannot have? 2. If all you want is to allow configuration from outside the crate, then the trait approach should work well.

Answer (score 0):

The OnceCell type in Rust is used to handle a scenario where you want to initialize something exactly once and then never change it again. This behavior makes it a good fit for constants whose values are determined at runtime (as opposed to compile-time constants).

Given that you're working on audio processing nodes on micro-controllers and require a "constant state" determined at runtime, OnceCell offers an ergonomic and safe solution.